# Trying to improve quality and efficiency of my VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, switch-statement, excel-2007

I have 50,000 name and address strings each occupying one cell. In order to Split the cell out to different Name, Street Number, Street, City etc I am trying to split the cells to columns that match either Street Number and Or Street Name.

- Cell Examples all in column E:

  > Row      Col: E
  >
  > 1. aparts. 56 Johnston Terrace Keyham Road
  > 2. 90 & 92 Wolseley Road
  > 3. 2 Ainslie Terrace
  > 4. Dyer & Cleaner 10 & 12 Mount Gold Road
  > 5. 48b Alexander Road
  > 6. Dairy Farmer Stratham Priory Road
- NewCell  Result in columns;

  > Row.  Col.F     |   Col.G      |     Col.H
  >
  > 1. aparts.|    56        | Johnston Terrace Keyham Road
  > 2. '*'  |   90 & 92 |    Wolseley Road
  > 3. '*'  |    2  | Ainslie Terrace
  > 4. Dyer & Cleaner  |  10 & 12  |  Mount Gold Road
  > 5. '*'   |  48b   |     Alexander Road
  > 6. Dairy Farmer  | '*' |  Stratham Priory Road

At the present my Excel Sheet does not have specific column names, only A; B; C etc. I have VBA code that will separate each cell. However, the Street Number and/or Street Name will be split differently depending on the "textnumbertext" string in each cell.
I have separate VBA code to add an asterisk in front of any entry that starts with a Street Number (see Code). This then places each cell in the correct column (I can delete the asterisk later). However, I feel that this code is inefficient and perhaps could be less verbose if perhaps I were to use the Case function.

A further complication is some Street numbers will be 14A or 12B or 10c, or 12a. If I add these options to the below code then everything becomes very long winded and inefficient. Any thoughts please?

```
Sub ReplaceFirstNumber()
'If the first character in the string starts with a number between 1-9 THEN 
'ADD a * to the string
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set r = Range(Range("E1"), Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown))
    For Each c In r
     If Left(c.Value, 1) = "1" _
     Or Left(c.Value, 1) = "2" _
     Or Left(c.Value, 1) = "3" _
     Or Left(c.Value, 1) = "4" _
     Or Left(c.Value, 1) = "5" _
     Or Left(c.Value, 1) = "6" _
     Or Left(c.Value, 1) = "7" _
     Or Left(c.Value, 1) = "8" _
     Or Left(c.Value, 1) = "9" Then
     c.Value = " * " & c.Value
    End If
   Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: When working with such data you should consider using arrays, your code will speed up a lot. I would give you an example, but because you only showed the part taking the address what Tim wrote is good.

Comment: Hi Damian Thanks for the comments. As you see from my comment to Tim I get a compile error using his code. I will edit my post to include typical cell entries that I am working on.

Comment: I have worked on such data and I think practically if you can write a code that can extract your required data that code alone would be complex enough to give you a hard time, your priority should be the actual logic, not the efficiency, as I believe you would have to run it only a few times

Comment: Well @usmanhaq the OP said that his code works, but way too slow so now that his logic is ok at least, he can focus on the optimization.

Comment: usmanhaq Thank you for your comment. Yes you are correct the list will take several steps to breakdown the cell string into manageable segments. I am new to VBA and was just looking find improvements to make the process easier.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The problem here is coding something that can handle all possible situations. How do you code where to split the data into `Name, Street Number, Street,` and *where* does each piece od data starts and ends? And of course, how you code a missing data? the empty part

Comment: @DJP2019 with the example you gave there is just no way that you can do this... there is no pattern on your input. Did you really manage to get the outputs with these inputs? If there was at least always the  street number you could half do it (taking the city would be a little bit complicated), but there are cases where you have no number... How do you detect if it's street name or name?

Comment: Hi Foxfire And Burns And Burns. The text string in cell E is not uniform or standard format, it is variable. Sometimes street number sometimes not sometime House name sometimes not. I have already 'broken' out in to separate cells the Name details (ie: Mrs. Joy Smith" and the County details (ie: Devon or Cornwall etc). The middle section is what I am working on. I have code that will take the middle section comprised of text number text and this works but I need to artificially include something in what would be an empty cell in order to put the data into the correct columns. Hence this code

Answer (score 0):

The function below will hopefully help you make this task a tad easier. It strips all numeric characters from the address string, and will include any trailing single letters.

```
Function getnumbersfromstring(address As String) As String
    For i = 1 To Len(address)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(address, i, 1)) Then getnumbersfromstring = getnumbersfromstring & Mid(address, i, 1) 
    Next i

    CharAfterNumber = Mid(address, Instr(1, address, getnumbersfromstring) + Len(getnumbersfromstring), 1)
    If IsNumeric(CharAfterNumber) = False And Not CharAfterNumber = " " And Not CharAfterNumber = "" Then
        getnumbersfromstring = getnumbersfromstring & CharAfterNumber
    End If
End Function
```

This function can be called in a regular Sub like so

```
Sub breakupaddress()

Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim addressnr As String

On Error Resume Next
Set r = Range(Range("E1"), Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown))
    For Each c In r
        addressnr = getnumbersfromstring(c.Value)
        MsgBox "The address number is '" & addressnr & "'.", vbInformation, "Information"
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim Stack Thank you for taking the time to help me out. I have tried running the  Sub routine but get an error  on line "addressnr = getnumbersfromstring(c). Visual basic says Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch.

Comment: `c` should be `c.Value` as `c` is a range and the Function expects a string. Edited the code!

Comment: Hi Tim Stack I am new to this site and to the formats for posting info. I have just tried to give examples of my cell values and the desired result. When I typed here it was formatted to make it easy to follow, ie Like a Before and After. However when I entered the update to the question all the new text formatting was lost! I obviously need to learn about how to post correctly.

Comment: No way of making sure the addresses are more... structured? This is a volatile mess  if you ask me

Comment: Hi Tim Slack Yes it is a mess and I don't like it - I have tried to improve the result layout to show which columns will have entries and which will not. I am new to this site and I am learning how to post. Thank you for you help and assistance. BTW In the Sub routine I am getting a Syntax error on the Megbox line which I will now try to resolve.

Comment: Not talking about your post, but rather the way the addresses are constructed. Are these the result from user input? In this case it would make your work a lot easier if these were inputted in a restricted single form, e.g. (nr.[+app.], street, city)

Comment: The data came from a PDF which just converted to single line text strings.

Comment: In that case I don't see an easy way to convert these strings to separate columns without the use of user input or machine learning. Especially with the last example, the lack of an address number leaves VBA to completely guess what the street and city is. It has no clear indication of knowing. What if the street name has three separate words and the city one? Or 2 and 1? Or 1 and 1? Too many variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about how you will code everything, but about your question, something that might work would be:

```
Sub ReplaceFirstNumber()
'If the first character in the string starts with a number between 1-9 THEN 
'ADD a * to the string
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range
Set r = Range("E1:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each c In r
     If IsNumeric(Left(c.Value, 1))=True Then c.Value = "*" & c.Value
   Next c
End Sub
```

In your code you use `Range(Range("E1"), Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown))`. This means **all cells in column E!**. And that's like a million cells in Excel 2007 or higher. In my code, the range is `Set r = Range("E1:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` This will select only all cells between E1 and the last non blank cell in Column E, so it will improve executing times *a lot* if you have only 50.000 rows of data.

Also, if you are learning VBA, I strongly encourage you to never use `On Error Resume Next` statement, because it hides errors, but they still occur.

Hope you can finally code this, or at least, find this answer helpful.

But anyways, you still got a lot to code.

Comment: Foxfire And Burns And Burns Brilliant! I knew in my heart that there was an improvement on my code which does work but your code works much better. Yeah! This is helping me learn VBA and try to keep it simple. Your Range comment is extremely useful I have used that before but overlooked it in my example, so Thank You again. Noted regarding On Error.